# Find matching files in a folder (minus file extension) and move them to a new folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a directory of files that contain both Word and PDF files. Some of the Word files in the directory have the same filename (minus extension) as the PDF files in the same directory. I have setup a simple C# winforms application to loop through the files and move the Word documents that have same name as PDF documents. Here's what I have so far. I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
        string[] filesWORD = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test\", "*.docx");
        List<string> resultFiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in filesWORD)
        {
            var finalfile = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf(".")); // removes everything after period in name.
            resultFiles.Add(finalfile);
            listBox1.DataSource = resultFiles.Distinct().ToList(); // placing the Word files in listBox1
        }

        string[] filesPDF = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test\", "*.pdf");
        List<string> resultFilesPDF = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in filesPDF)
        {
            var finalfile = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf(".")); 
            resultFilesPDF.Add(finalfile);
            listBox2.DataSource = resultFilesPDF.Distinct().ToList(); // placing the PDF files in listBox2
        }            

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            //IF the WORD files in listBox1 match the PDF files in listBox2 -- move them to a new folder.
            foreach (string files in listBox1.Items)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items == listBox2.Items)
                {
                    //Get Filename                    
                    var filename = Path.GetFileName(files + ".docx");
                    //Move Files
                    File.Move(files + ".docx", @"c:\test2\" + "\\" + filename);
                }                   

            }
        }
```

Comment: *"I'm not sure why this isn't working"* we are not sure why it is not working either. what have you done to debug this?

Comment: `listBox2.Items` is the collection of items in the listbox, you want to iterate over individual items in it, so like the first listbox, iterate over the second as well and then compares files (from listbox1) with the file2 for listbox 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final for loop is where the problem is, you can try this (need to add listbox for your case), you are comparing the wrong thing, also the outer for loop is not required.

```
foreach (var pdfFile in resultFilesPDF)
        {
            foreach (var wordFile in resultFiles)
            {
                if (wordFile == pdfFile)
                {
                    //Get Filename                    
                    var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(wordFile + ".docx");
                    //Move Files
                    File.Move(wordFile + ".docx", @"c:\test2\" + "\\" + filename);
                }
            }
        }
```

Using Linq you can do it like, be aware that if you try to move the same file multiple times the Move method might blow up.

```
   var sameNames = resultFiles.SelectMany(w => resultFilesPDF.Where(p => p == w));
    sameNames.ToList().ForEach(file =>
    {
        File.Move(file + ".docx", @"c:\test2\" + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file + ".docx"));
    });
```